# Dependency Inject Blazor Version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-client-side

i wan to use Dependency Injection in blazor i am using visual studio preview the latest version i want to add this code in startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<SengaltonServices>();
```

[but i can not find startup.cs in client to inject in Razor component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VypNc.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Blazor WASM you setup the DI in `Program` using `WebAssemblyHostBuilder.Services`:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
       var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
       builder.Services.AddSingleton<SengaltonServices>();
       await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```